# Optional chaining for Python objects: foo?.bar?.baz

Tags: python, python-3.x

In JavaScript, if I'm not sure whether every element of the chain exists/is not undefined, I can do `foo?.bar`, and if `bar` does not exist on `foo`, the interpreter will silently short circuit it and not throw an error.

Is there anything similar in Python? For now, I've been doing it like this:

```py
if foo and foo.bar and foo.bar.baz:
    # do something
```

My intuition tells me that this isn't the best way to check whether every element of the chain exists. Is there a more elegant/Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What you want is PEP 505  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for but the maybe-dot and maybe-subscript operators haven't been added to Python (yet?)

Comment: Maybe? I'm not certain because I'm not privileged enough to use Py 3.8 yet, but it appears to have been ratified?

Comment: It's not in Python 3.8. PEP 505 is marked as Deferred which means no progress is being made. See discussion at https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-505-status/4612.

Comment: Are you asking for Python objects or Python dictionaries?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was objects, not dicts. That said, neither of them support optional chaining, so the question is open to both.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone who comes to this question because they wish the language had native support for such a feature: the place to advocate for that is the [Python discourse forum](https://discuss.python.org/), not here. But please keep in mind that *they* have already had that discussion many times.

Answer (score 31):

If it's a dictionary you can use `get(keyname, value)`

```py
{'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}.get('foo', {}).get('bar')
```

Comment: If the value of 'foo' is None it will fall

Comment: so cumbersome, it seems that only reasonable option is to use pydash

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```py
getattr(getattr(foo, 'bar', None), 'baz', None)
```

Comment: This is't more readable than what OP has `if foo and foo.bar and foo.bar.baz:`

Comment: @KuldeepJain While it may not be more readable, `if foo and foo.bar and foo.bar.baz:` does not work because it will raise an `AttributeError`. This answer at least works like optional chaining in that it won't raise an exception and you'll get `None` back if a part of the chain is missing.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense in case `bar` or `baz` is missing it will. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 23):

Most pythonic way is:

```py
try:
    # do something
    ...
except (NameError, AttributeError) as e:
    # do something else
    ...
```

Comment: I wish there was a way to downvote python here :'(

Comment: This will still make your static type checking put out an error.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the Glom.

```
from glom import glom

target = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}
glom(target, 'a.b.c', default=None)  # returns 'd'
```

https://github.com/mahmoud/glom

Answer (score 6):

Combining a few things I see here.

```
from functools import reduce


def optional_chain(obj, keys):
    try:
        return reduce(getattr, keys.split('.'), obj)
    except AttributeError:
        return None

optional_chain(foo, 'bar.baz')
```

Or instead extend `getattr` so you can also use it as a drop-in replacement for `getattr`

```py
from functools import reduce


def rgetattr(obj, attr, *args):
    def _getattr(obj, attr):
        return getattr(obj, attr, *args)
    return reduce(_getattr, attr.split('.'), obj)
```

With `rgetattr` it can still raise an `AttributeError` if the path does not exist, and you can specify your own default instead of None.

Comment: the `optional_chain` example has a couple bugs. the reduce should be returned, and `root` doesn't exist, it should be `obj`

Answer (score 5):

Combining some of the other answers into a function gives us something that's easily readable and something that can be used with objects and dictionaries.

```
def optional_chain(root, *keys):
    result = root
    for k in keys:
        if isinstance(result, dict):
            result = result.get(k, None)
        else:
            result = getattr(result, k, None)
        if result is None:
            break
    return result
```

Using this function you'd just add the keys/attributes after the first argument.

```
obj = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}
print(optional_chain(obj, 'a', 'b'), optional_chain(obj, 'a', 'z'))
```

Gives us:

```
{'c': {'d': 1}} None
```

Answer (score 4):

Classes can override `__getattr__` to return a default value for missing attributes:

```
class Example:
    def __getattr__(self, attr): # only called when missing
        return None
```

Testing it:

```
>>> ex = Example()
>>> ex.attr = 1
>>> ex.attr
1
>>> ex.missing # evaluates to `None
>>>
```

However, this will not allow for chaining:

```
>>> ex.missing.missing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'missing'
```

Nor will it deal with attempts to call methods that are absent:

```
>>> ex.impossible()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

To fix this, we can make a proxy object:

```
class GetAnything:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): # also allow calls to work
        return self
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Missing value>'

# Reassign the name to avoid making more instances
GetAnything = GetAnything()
```

And return that instead of `None`:

```
class Example:
    def __getattr__(self, attr): # only called when missing
        return GetAnything
```

Now it chains as desired:

```
>>> Example().missing_attribute.missing_method().whatever
<Missing value>
```

Comment: One might ask: "why not just inherit from the `GetAnything` class instead of defining another `__getattr__`?" If you do that, then something like `Example().missing_method().valid_attribute` *would unexpectedly succeed*, supposing that the `Example` instance has a `valid_attribute` but no `missing_method` - the `missing_method` proxy call would return the same `Example` instance, allowing the `valid_attribute` to be looked up. This is probably not what you want. Once a lookup has "failed", it makes sense to keep coming back to the same object - but not the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some syntactic sugar to make chaining with `getattr` look more like the fluent interfaces of other languages. It's definitely not "Pythonic", but it allows for something simpler to write.

The idea is to abuse the `@` operator added in Python 3.5 (to support matrix multiplication in Numpy). We define a class `r` such that its instances, when matrix-multiplied on the right of another object, invoke `getattr`. (The combination `@r`, of course, is read "attr".)

```
class r:
    def __init__(self, name, value=None):
        self._name = name
        self._value = value
    def __rmatmul__(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, self._name, self._value)
```

Now we can chain attribute accesses easily, without having to modify any other classes (and of course it works on built-in types):

```
>>> 'foo'@r('bar')@r('baz') # None
>>>
```

However, the order of operations is inconvenient with method calls:

```
>>> 'foo bar'@r('split')()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'r' object is not callable
>>> ('foo bar'@r('split'))()
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.10 introduced the [`match` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement) in [PEP-634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/), with the tutorial in [PEP-636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) being a nice reference.

This statement allow these sorts of "chained" operations to be performed, but note that they are statements and not expressions.

For example, OP could instead do:

```
match foo:
    case object(bar=object(baz=baz)) if baz:
        # do something with baz
```

The reason for needing `object` is that everything is a subtype of it and hence it always succeeds.  It then goes on to check that the attribute exists, which might fail.  Exceptions wouldn't be thrown if the attribute didn't exist, just the `case` wouldn't match and it would move onto the next one (which in this case doesn't exist, so nothing would be done).

A more realistic example would check something more specific, e.g.:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['bar'])
Bar = namedtuple('Bar', ['baz'])

def fn(x):
    match x:
        case Foo(bar=Bar(baz=baz)):
            return baz

print(fn(Foo(bar=Bar(baz='the value'))))
print(fn(None))
print(fn(1))
```

which would output:

```
the value
None
None
```

If instead you wanted to destructure into dictionaries, you might use something like:

```
foo = {'bar': {'baz': 'the value'}}

match foo:
    case {'bar': {'baz': baz}}:
        print(baz)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use reduce to achieve Javascript-like optional chaining in Python

```
from functools import reduce


data_dictionary = {
    'foo': {
        'bar': {
            'buzz': 'lightyear'
        },
        'baz': {
            'asd': 2023,
            'zxc': [
                {'patrick': 'star'},
                {'spongebob': 'squarepants'}
            ],
            'qwe': ['john', 'sarah']
        }
    },
    'hello': {
        'world': 'hello world',
    },
}


def optional_chaining_v1(dictionary={}, *property_list):
    def reduce_callback(current_result, current_dictionary):
        if current_result is None:
            return dictionary.get(current_dictionary)
        if type(current_result) != dict:
            return None
        return current_result.get(current_dictionary)
    return reduce(reduce_callback, property_list, None)


# or in one line
optional_chaining_v1 = lambda dictionary={}, *property_list: reduce(lambda current_result, current_dictionary: dictionary.get(current_dictionary) if current_result is None else None if type(current_result) != dict else current_result.get(current_dictionary), property_list, None)

# usage
optional_chaining_v1_result1 = optional_chaining_v1(data_dictionary, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')
print('optional_chaining_v1_result1:', optional_chaining_v1_result1)
optional_chaining_v1_result2 = optional_chaining_v1(data_dictionary, 'foo', 'bar', 'buzz')
print('optional_chaining_v1_result2:', optional_chaining_v1_result2)

# optional_chaining_v1_result1: None
# optional_chaining_v1_result2: lightyear


def optional_chaining_v2(dictionary={}, list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot=''):
    property_list = list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot.split('.')

    def reduce_callback(current_result, current_dictionary):
        if current_result is None:
            return dictionary.get(current_dictionary)
        if type(current_result) != dict:
            return None
        return current_result.get(current_dictionary)
    return reduce(reduce_callback, property_list, None)


# or in one line
optional_chaining_v2 = lambda dictionary={}, list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot='': reduce(lambda current_result, current_dictionary: dictionary.get(current_dictionary) if current_result is None else None if type(current_result) != dict else current_result.get(current_dictionary), list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot.split('.'), None)

# usage
optional_chaining_v2_result1 = optional_chaining_v2(data_dictionary, 'foo.bar.baz')
print('optional_chaining_v2_result1:', optional_chaining_v2_result1)
optional_chaining_v2_result2 = optional_chaining_v2(data_dictionary, 'foo.bar.buzz')
print('optional_chaining_v2_result2:', optional_chaining_v2_result2)

# optional_chaining_v2_result1: None
# optional_chaining_v2_result2: lightyear
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [safebag](https://github.com/galeNightIn/safebag).

I was just about to publish something like this, but found that there's already this package

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing

from safebag import chain, get_value


@dataclass
class Node:
    data: int
    node: typing.Optional["Node"]


nodes = Node(
    data=1, 
    node=Node(
        data=2, 
        node=None
    )
)

# construct chain
chain(nodes)
# ChainProxy(data_object=Node(data=1, node=Node(data=2, node=None)), bool_hook=False)

# access existing data
get_value(chain(nodes).node.data)
# 2

# chain for non existing data
get_value(chain(nodes).foo.bar.baz)
# None
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this at work. Python does have the `hasattr` built in, which can perform the check before you try to access an attribute. It's clunky, but it works:

```
foo.bar if hasattr(foo, "bar") else None
```