# Python return on Nonetype operator (like ? in Javascript)

Tags: python

In Python I have the following code:

```py
if player:
    player.draw(image)
```

I know that in Javascript I could to the following to simplify this:

```js
player?.draw(image)
```

Is there an equivalent in Python to the Javascript `?` (return on nullable) operator.

This is probably a duplicate, but I don't know the names of the operators so Googling didn't help me out much.

Comment: sounds similar to ternary operator, but it's a little different

Comment: I would say the closest would be `player.draw(image) if player else None` but it's not that readable.

Comment: Not really, no. `player and player.draw()` is an option, but frowned upon and just as repetitive. `try: player.draw() except TypeError: pass` would be the pythonic ask-for-forgiveness approach, but that's even longer…

Comment: IMHO the Python code you've shown is perfect. It's easy to read, efficient and clear to anyone who needs to maintain your code what the intention is

Comment: Duplicate: [Optional chaining in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64285182/3890632)