# Python3: is there an elegant way to check nested attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for now I use this:

```
print(theObject.nestedObjectOne.NestedObjectTwo.NestedObjectThree if theObject and theObject.NestedOBjectOne and theObject.NestedObjectOne.NestedObjectTwo else "n/a")
```

In order to support a case where `NestedObjectOne` is None.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Yes, I know I can write a function to traverse the object and check attributes recursively. I'm asking if there's any construct in python that does this as elegantly as ES6 for instance:

```
console.log(theObj?.theFirstNested?.theSecondNested)
```

Comment: What would you expect the call to `print()` to print when any of them isn't defined?

Comment: No, there isn't. You'd be stuck with smart uses of getattr, or write that function.

Comment: @Grismar None, obv.

Comment: @njzk2 I don't think that's obvious at all, which is why I'm asking OP.

Comment: @Grismar OP gave an example of how that looks in other languages, which demonstrates the expected behaviour

Comment: @njzk2, I'm sure you're trying to be helpful, but I suggest allowing OP to point out what is obvious in response to valid questions about their question.

Comment: There is nothing that *easy* in Python. Elegance is a matter of opinion. Python philosophy is that "Errors should never pass silently, unless explicitly silenced." The closest you'll get is `getattr` specifying a default, which at least allows you to write the whole thing as a single "flowing" expression. I closed as a duplicate with the reference for how to use `getattr` - because otherwise, this is simply opinion based and not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The more elegant way to do this (IMO) is `try/except`.  Access the deepest item directly, then catch the `AttributeError` if any.

Comment: @Samwise well, sure, if you want any missing attribute on the chain to be handled the same way. But you can also do that in other languages.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel although the linked question provides an answer to how to implement 1 way of solving this, it doesn't actually answer OP's question. `try .. except` or implementing or modifying the class to fail in an expected way are other solutions that go unmentioned there.

Comment: so, that would look like `getattr(getattr(getattr(theObject, "nestedObjectOne", None), "nestedObjectTwo", None), "nestedObjectThree", None)`?

Comment: @Grismar then it needs to be edited to be more objective - i.e., to give specific criteria for what is or isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: @njzk2 yes; that's why I said it isn't easy. But `getattr` is the unique tool that *works the same way* that `?.` does in the ES6 example.

Comment: I think this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285182/optional-chaining-in-python is a better duplicate. It explicitly offers a couple of options, and links to the pep proposal for optional chaining: https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/

Comment: @njzk2 agreed. I would have swapped that in, if the question hadn't been reopened. I'll leave it to the rest of you, then.

Comment: Python 3.10s `match` statements get somewhat close if you're happy relying on something that recent

Comment: Came up with an answer, but agree that the alternative closer covers the bases, other than extending the class - someone is welcome to go and add it there, if they like :)

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416977/1358308) to the referred question that shows how to use `match` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Whether code should fail or just return some default value is a matter of opinion or style. Where ES6 defaults to `undefined`, other languages might pick something like `null` - in Python you might expect `None`.

However, multiple choices are available, and for some types, a value of `0` might make sense and `None` could cause havoc, so Python chooses to cause your code to fail when it accesses non-existent attributes.

There's a few ways to deal with it gracefully though.

`try .. except`:

```
try:
    x = theObject.nestedObjectOne.NestedObjectTwo.NestedObjectThree
except AttributeError:
    x = None  # or whatever value makes the most sense
```

Without exceptions:

```
x = getattr(
        getattr(
            getattr(
                theObject, 'nestedObjectOne', None
            ), 
            'nestedObjectTwo', None
        ), 
        'nestedObjectThree', None
    )
```

(obviously, you can write it on a single line if you don't mind the lack of readability)

Or you could modify the class so that it deals with the case of a non-existent attribute gracefully itself, which can make sense in specific case without being "unpythonic".

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    has_this = 42

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[item]
        else:
            return None


x = MyClass()
print(x.has_this)
print(x.does_not_have_this)
```

Note that this is a somewhat simplistic and incomplete way to implement this, it's here to show the direction you could be looking in. Of course, you can have `MyClass` inherit from any other class, to add the behaviour to an existing class.

Comment: Modifying MyClass like that will not allow for chaining; `x.missing.also_missing` will raise an exception because `None` doesn't have an `also_missing` attribute and also doesn't have this `__getattr__` logic.

Comment: That's a good point - whatever is returned instead of None should have the same capabilities. Not going to update it, since the question is closed - it's worth remarking though.

Comment: I added an answer at the linked duplicate to refine that technique.